# how to access the div elements from .cs side by adding a method to ImageButton in c#

Tags: c#, htmlgenericcontrol

This method is in a cs class which is not in a  webForm in there I create some div and classes but I want to create a method `( objImage.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "amethod(objRssItem)"); )` amethod is in another .cs which is in a webform. I cannot work this method when i click the imagebutton.
How can i do it? thanks

```
public HtmlGenericControl CreateDIV_OyVerme_Sub_Yildiz(string id, int subId, Rss.Items objRssItem)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl objDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        objDiv.ID = strControlName_DivYildiz + id + "_" + subId;

        objDiv.Attributes.Add("class", strClassName_DivYildiz);
        //objDiv.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

        ImageButton objImage = new ImageButton();
        objImage.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

        //objImage.Src = strImgSrc_yildiz;
        //objImage.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(WebForm4.ImageButtons_Click);


        objImage.ID = strControlName_ImageYildiz + id +"_" + subId;;
        objImage.ImageUrl = strImgSrc_yildiz;
        objImage.OnClientClick = strOnClientClickFunc_yildiz;
        objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "19px");
        objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "20px");
        objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderWidth, "0px");
        objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position, "relative");
        objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Top, "13px");
        objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Left, "6px");
        objImage.Style.Add("float", "left");
        objImage.ToolTip = subId + "/" + 5;
        // calling the method 
        objImage.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "amethod(objRssItem)");
        objDiv.Controls.Add(objImage);

        return objDiv;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OnClientClick is for JavaScript.  I believe you are looking to call a cs method.  If you want to call a cs method then it should be clear.  You use the click function of the code behind for the button.  If the problem is this is a dynamic object (as you show.)  Then try this

```
  objImage.Click += myfunctiontocall;
```

Remember this will happen in postback and if you don't re-create the object (with the same click handler) the call of your function will not work.  You need to "re-wire" it every time.

---

To give a parameter to an event you can wrap a closure like so.

```
  var duck = objRssItem;

  objImage.Click += (s,e) => { WebForm4.amethod (duck); };
```

Remember closures are a tricky business -- you are calling amethod with what has become  global.  Strange things can happen.

Comment: I write  objImage.Click += WebForm4.amethod (objRssItem);  but i does not work and it gives an error which is cannot simpicity convert void to .....

Comment: A click event can't have a parameter.

Comment: I'll post a way to do it with a closure.

Comment: it does not give any error but when i click the imagebutton it does not enter the method maybe method style is false:  method is like  }
        public static void amethod( Rss.Items objRssItem)
        {
            string rss = objRssItem.rss_id;
      
        }

Comment: Remember this will happen in postback and if you don't re-create the object (with the same click handler) the call of your function will not work. You need to "re-wire" it every time.

Comment: The function you show above -- where is that function running.  If it is not page load then it won't rewire it everytime the page loads.